# Create Duplicate with changing value data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I have to create duplicate of row and  changing a value with data flow ? it's possible ?

Thanks a lots for your help

Best,

Nicolas M.

Comment: you can achieve that by adding a union activity, then add an alter row activity in a dataflow. let me know if you need further help 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-union